# created new class in android but can't figure out context

Tags: android

I created a new class in android that creates LinearLayouts when instantiated. However I can't figure out the context to put in the brackets of: `new LinearLayout(context)`. Can someone shed some light? (I've already tried reading everything i can on contexts)

I'm assuming I don't need to extend Activity in my class

```
public class NewLayouts {
...
newParentLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()); //<--eclipse warns of error here saying not a valid context
newParentLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
newParentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
TextView monthDisplay = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); //<--eclipse warns of error here saying not a valid context
...
}
```

My main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        NewLayouts Sample = new NewLayouts(1,2); //variables required in my constructor for new Layouts
        setContentView(Sample.newParentLayout);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do but `setContentView(...)` requires either a resource identifier to identify an xml layout file or it needs a pre-inflated `View`. Regardless of your problem with the `Context`, unless `NewLayouts extends View`, then `setContentView(Sample);` is going to fail anyway.

Comment: @Squonk Okay, I wrote this sample pretty quickly so I missed that, but my code actually is referencing a LinearLayout. I've edited to show that my actual code is `setContentView(Sample.newParentLayout)`. With that in mind, any idea what I should be putting in the context field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the constructor of `NewLayouts` to be something like...

```
public NewLayouts(Context ctx, int X, int Y) {...}
```

...then use `ctx` as the `Context` in `NewLayouts` for creating the `Views`.

In the `Activity` then do the following...

```
NewLayouts Sample = new NewLayouts(this, 1, 2);
```

That will pass the `Activity's` own `Context` into `NewLayouts` constructor.

Comment: Thank you! This worked and it will help me greatly going forward whenever I create classes.

Answer (score 0):

try `new LinearLayout(this)` or `new LinearLayout(newLayouts.this)`

Comment: I've tried this, getApplicationContext(), and getBaseContext(). I just tried NewLayouts.this but that doesn't work either

Comment: @JuanManuel : As `NewLayouts` doesn't extend `Context` (directly or indirectly) your suggestion can't possibly work.